# How do I map parent class DTO to parent class entity

Tags: java, modelmapper

I have the following class hierarchy:

```
public class BaseFaultType
{
    protected String faultId;
    protected String faultDescription;
    protected String faultDetail;

    ... -> setters and getters
}

public class PollingFaultType extends BaseFaultType
{
    protected Integer initiatedFiles;
    protected Integer failedFiles;
    ... -> getters and setters
}

public class StoreFaultType extends BaseFaultType
{
    protected String storePath;
    ... -> getters and setters
}

...
```

There is one BaseFaultType with some common properties (I left out most of them for simplicity) and then I have multiple types that extend the BaseFaultType with additional properties.

Please note that I have no control over these classes.

My application receives objects of these child types. 
Then I need to map these objects into different types of entities, i.e:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = EntityConstants.ERROR)
public class FaultMessage
{
    private String errorId;
    private String errorDescription;
    private String errorDetail;
    private Boolean retryable;
    ... -> getters and setters
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = EntityConstants.POLLING_MESSAGE)
public class PollingFaultMessage extends FaultMessage
{
    private Integer failed;
    private Integer initiated;
    ... -> getters and setters
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = EntityConstants.STORE_MESSAGE)
public class StoreFaultMessage 
{
    ...
}
```

I am using ModelMapper for this job.
Note that the ModelMapper that I use is configured with disabled implicit mapping (for reasons that are not interesting for this question):

```
mapper.getConfiguration().setImplicitMappingEnabled(false);
mapper.addMappings(new PropertyMap<BaseFaultType, FaultMessage>()
        {
            @Override
            protected void configure()
            {
                map(source.getFaultId()).setErrorId(null);
                map(source.getFaultDescription()).setErrorDescription(null);
                ...
            }
        });
mapper.addMappings(new PropertyMap<PollingFaultType, PollingFaultMessage>()
    {
        @Override
        protected void configure()
        {
            map(source.getInitiatedFiles()).setInitiated(null);
            ...
        }

    });
PollingFaultType faultType = getPollingFaultType();
PollingFaultMessage faultMessage = mapper.map(faultType, PollingFaultMessage.class);
```

Unfortunately, this produces faultMessage that only has its `initiated` property mapped to a real value.
The properties `errorId`, `errorDetail` etc are not being mapped (probably since they are configured into a completely separate TypeMap)

So my question is - how can I configure ModelMapper in a way that allows me to define TypeMaps/PropertyMaps that only map child-specific properties such as `initiated` and `failed` and have the *common* properties that come from the base type such as `errorId` and `errorDetail` automatically mapped?
The main thing I want to achieve here is that I want to avoid having to explicitly specify the mapping of these *common* properties in each child's TypeMap, i.e. I want to avoid to:

```
mapper.addMappings(new PropertyMap<PollingFaultType, PollingFaultMessage>()
        {
            @Override
            protected void configure()
            {
                // I want to avoid to copy these lines around for each child mapping since they will be always the same
                map(source.getFaultId()).setErrorId(null);
                map(source.getFaultDescription()).setErrorDescription(null);


                map(source.getInitiatedFiles()).setInitiated(null);
                ...
            }

        });
```

Comment: Please, tell me your version of modelmapper.

Comment: Latest - 1.1.1
I just noticed the includeBase() method of the TypeMap. Now I am experimenting with it but is seems this is the way to go

Comment: yep, you are on the right way :)

Comment: check my example. I hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do next:

beans:

```
public class BaseType {
    protected String base;
    // getters/setters
}
public class Extended extends  BaseType {

    private String value ;
    // getters/setters
}
```

dto:

```
public class SimpleDTO {
    private String valueDTO;
    private String baseDTO;
    // getters/setters
}
```

configuration:

```
modelMapper.typeMap(SimpleDTO.class, BaseType.class)
                .addMapping(SimpleDTO::getBaseDTO, BaseType::setBase);
modelMapper.typeMap(SimpleDTO.class, Extended.class)
                .addMapping(SimpleDTO::getValueDTO, Extended::setValue)
                .includeBase(SimpleDTO.class, BaseType.class);
```

use:

```
SimpleDTO dto = new SimpleDTO();
dto.setBaseDTO("base");
dto.setValueDTO("value");
Extended ex = modelMapper.map(dto, Extended.class);
```

ModelMapper version: **1.1.0**